# Where are Reference Properties stored

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto

When creating a VSTO project it's important to preserve the reference *properties*, for example the Embedded Interop Types (True/False), so I wan't to include this information in version control.  I can't see any reference to these in the .csproj structure, where are they stored?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick experiment on my system by switching reference to the embedded interop for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll from True to False

And I saw that the .csproj file is getting updated, for the Word assembly it is now.

```
<EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that.